# Mysterious hidden 'Reset your password' modal just under the body tag in Meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I use accounts-password in my meteor web-app, but only on two pages, where I include the usual `{{> loginButtons }}` code.

But a permanent hidden (`display: none`) modal with a title of 'Reset your Password' appears in the source just below the `body` tag, on every page. In other words it's in my layout, as a permanent part of my single page app, and I didn't put it there. It's appeared by itself, above the first piece of code in my layout, right below the `<body>` tag.

[image]

If I change the css display attribute to 'block', this is what appears:

[image]

No code of mine includes this modal, so I have no idea why it's there, and I would like to remove it, if possible.

As stated above, I do use accounts-password on a couple of pages, but so far I have used all the defaults, I haven't tailored the package in any way.

Can anybody shed any light on this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because actually in my opinion it's just a bug and needs reporting to the makers of the package

Answer (score 0):

[This modal is declared in the `accounts-ui-unstyled` package](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-ui-unstyled/login_buttons_dialogs.html#L138) which is a dependance of `accounts-ui` you're probably using.

Packages have the ability to declare global scoped templates and might include them on your behalf or when including a package-declared template such as `{{> loginButtons}}`, it's not a bug, it's a feature :)

I would recommend you leave the modal as it is, after all it's hidden by CSS and won't interfere with your normal app flow.

You may want to use another user accounts UI package such as [`useraccounts`](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/).

You could also come up with your own `accounts-ui` behavior, drop the standard package and no longer use `{{> loginButtons}}`, but think twice : is it worth the trade ?

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. But now I reckon it's a bug not a feature. It's part of accounts-ui-bootstrap-3, and I think I shall file a bug report. I shouldn't have wasted yours and other people's time here, and in fact I shall close this.